# Ajax : passing input box value to C# codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an AJAX almost working. I can get it to execute a simple function and return a value such as the date and time.

My problem now is developing the script to send the value of an input box to the C# function and then using this value in the code. So that a the correct string can be returned.

If sombody could check if am doing it right or where am going wrong then that would be great

thanks

Ajax Code

```
 $(document).ready(function ste() {
        // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
        $("#Result").click(function () {
            var thePostCode = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1__postCodeInput').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Add-Property.aspx/GetAverageRent",
                data: { PostCode: thePostCode },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                    $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                    alert("code was executed");
                    codeAddress();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

C# Function Code

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetAverageRent(string PostCode)
        {
            string Postcode = PostCode;
                var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
                var doc = webGet.Load("http://www.webaddress.com" + Postcode);


                HtmlNode AvgPrice = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='split2r right']//strong[@class='price big']");

                if (AvgPrice != null)
                {
                    return AvgPrice.InnerHtml.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Invalid Postcode!";
                }
        }
```

Markup

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="_postCodeInput">Post Code: </label>
                            <input type="text" runat="server" id="_postCodeInput" onchange="ste()" class="form-control"/>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="_pcodeRFV" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="_postCodeInput" ValidationGroup="saveProperty" ErrorMessage="Property Postcode" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                       <div id="Result">Click here for the time.</div>
```

Comment: And what is not working? Any error? At the first glance this: `"http://www.webaddress.com" + Postcode` does not look like a valid url

Comment: Yes was changed for security but basically when i click the #result div nothing happens. i was hoping that i was passing the input box value correctly seems nothing is happening... its asif the script is not working

Comment: `string Postcode = PostCode;` Does you C# program compile?

Comment: I don't think you understand what @Andrei is saying.  If you pass a postcode of PO11PO (for example) then what you have above will look for a URL of `http://www.webaddress.comPO11PO` which is obviously wrong, regardless of the base URL you use.

Comment: yes, well it gives no errors and as you can see the variables are capitalised differently. sorry the correct URI does have a "/" at the end before the postcode. The function has worked previously when not being used by Ajax EDIT: Does the code look like it should work tho?

Comment: "when i click the #result div nothing happens" check your developer tools, f.x. F12 in IE or CTRL+SHIFT+I in Chrome. Check the network tab for network messages and console for js bugs or logs.

Comment: Developer tools say   HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: any info on why i am getting this error would be great

Comment: That means your server code does not work as you expect it to. You need to debug it to see the exact error

Comment: I have norrowed it down to passing the value of the input box to the function as i tested it without passing and it worked (if i set postcode variable to a static value)